# More efficient query to get all symptoms of a specific bodypart?

Tags: mysql

**Is there a shorter/more efficient query to replace this?**

```
SELECT s_name 
FROM symptom, bodypart_symptoms, bodypart 
WHERE bodypart_symptoms.bp_id = bodypart.bp_id 
AND bodypart.bp_name = '$bodypart' 
AND symptom.s_id = bodypart_symptoms.s_id
```

**Table structure:**

*bodypart:* bp_id, bp_name

*bodypart_symptoms:* bp_id, s_id

*disease:* d_id, d_name

*disease_symptoms:* d_id, s_id

*symptom:* s_id, s_name

Comment: Use a join (a LEFT or RIGHT join could suffice here), and make sure there are indexes defined for the columns you join on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s_name 
FROM bodypart_symptoms
LEFT JOIN bodypart 
ON bodypart_symptoms.bp_id = bodypart.bp_id 
  AND bodypart.bp_name = '$bodypart' 
LEFT JOIN symptom
ON symptom.s_id = bodypart_symptoms.s_id
```

Comment: I tested both your answer and Aleksander's answer, and your answer seems to be a little faster (maybe because of the where statement?). Thank you for your help!

Comment: :-) thank you. and yes if you put some filters on `join` level it is more optimized than to put same clause in `where`

Answer (score 1):

You should use INNER JOIN like this

```
SELECT s_name
FROM symptom
INNER JOIN bodypart_simptoms
ON symptom.s_id = bodypart_symptoms.s_id
INNER JOIN bodypart 
ON bodypart_symptoms.bp_id = bodypart.bp_id 
WHERE bodypart.bp_name = '$bodypart'
```

Comment: I tested both your answer and Alex's answer, and his answers seems to be a little faster (maybe because of the where statement?). Thank you for your help!

Comment: you're welcome... yes i see Alex answered about 11 second before me, and yes when i see his answer i thought that it's better solution I just didn't want to change anything it would be stupid to do... So GL glad you find best solution...